# How to setup lots of cookies fast?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string `SID=hbewtrfdh;AAA_Cookie=1412f432g;OO=ferdbg4vw`. I can set add them via some plugin, but I'd have to do that thrice. Is it possible to add cookies just by adding a string somewhere, probably via command line with javascript?

Comment: You could create a bookmarklet that when clicked uses window.prompt() to let you type in that string, then it parses the string and creates the cookies.

Comment: What about setting cookies is not fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript cookies are as simple as setting the variable `document.cookie`.

Doing something similar to this should work for your scenario:

```
var cookies = "SID=hbewtrfdh;AAA_Cookie=1412f432g;OO=ferdbg4vw";
cookies = cookies.split(';');

for( var key in cookies ) {
    document.cookie = cookies[key] + "; path=/; max-age=60";
}
```

This would set up the 3 cookies all with the same path and max-age. Of course you can edit the extra parameters as you need.

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Comment: Ah, beautiful, should have thought of it myself.